# How to dampen value in script?

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I have a simple script that changes a position based on a bool. It works well, but I was wondering if there was a way to interpolate/dampen the value when it changes.

My script:

```
import random

if(is_out_of_range):
  pos = (target_pos.x + random.random(), target_pos.y + random.random(), 0)
else:
  pos = ground_target_pos
```

Comment: Please post scripts as text.

Comment: @batFINGER it's text now

Comment: What do you mean interpolate? Why random? Only one vertex?